# Can I use a unique variable in Meteor template each time?

Tags: javascript, meteor

In another template, I'm using 'articleSingle' template inside a loop.

```
{{#each articles}}
    {{> articleSingle}}
{{/each}}
```

The articleSingle template has this:

```
let publishTitleNonReactive;

Template.articleSingle.onCreated(function() {

    this.autorun(function() {
        if (Template.currentData() && !publishTitleNonReactive) {
            publishTitleNonReactive = Template.currentData().publishTitle;
        }
    });

});
```

I want this `publishTitleNonReactive` var to be unique or at least in a local scope so that I can have different value each time this template is being used.

Any idea how can I get there?

#### Update:

I'm trying to use the variable in a helper which is reactive right now. So, whenever the template data updates, it becomes undefined.

The helper I'm using in 'articleSingle' template:

```
titleHybrid: function(){
    return this.publishTitle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store properties in the template instance by using `this` in `onCreated`:

```
Template.articleSingle.onCreated(function () {
  this.publishTitleNonReactive = …
  …
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems properties are working well right after creating the template. However, I'm trying to use the variable in a helper which is reactive right now. So, whenever it updates any template data, it becomes undefined. Any help on that?

Comment: Can you add the code of that helper to your question?

Answer (score 0):

i think i understand what you're asking; can't you just push down the article data in each iteration?

```
{{#each article in articles}}
    {{> articleSingle article=article}}
{{/each}}

Template.articleSingle.onCreated(function() {
    let publishTitle = Template.currentData().article.publishTitle;
    this.publishTitle = new ReactiveVar(publishTitle);
});
```

or:

```
{{#each article in articles}}
    {{> articleSingle publishTitle=article.publishTitle}}
{{/each}}

Template.articleSingle.onCreated(function() {
    let publishTitle = Template.currentData().publishTitle;
    this.publishTitle = new ReactiveVar(publishTitle);
});
```

from there you can store the title in a reactive var to use it in helpers. you're keeping it in such a way that all instances of the template are sharing it.